# Symfony Form Theme extend inline

Tags: symfony, twig

I extend FosUserBundle register form like this:

```
{% extends "@App/base.html.twig" %}

{% form_theme form 'bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig' %}

{% block form_label_class -%}
   col-md-8
{%- endblock form_label_class %}
```

Unfortunately the block form_label_class which is from bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig is not extending there.

I want now in my form to use label as col-md-8 (instead the default col-sm-2) but then in another form maybe want to use col-md-6 and so on.

Is there an easy way to do it inline in every from instead create extends for each col-md-XX which is really not very convenient at all.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell Symfony to include your current template as a form theme:

```
{% form_theme form with [
    'bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig',
    _self,
] %}
```

Otherwise, it doesn't know to look in the current template for form theme blocks.

You can also use this to include other templates with form blocks as well. This is helpful if you have multiple templates that re-use the same form blocks; you can refactor them all into one template and reference it everywhere it's needed.

Comment: Please [do not use `_self` anymore](http://symfony.com/blog/security-release-twig-1-20-0).

Comment: Currently, there is no other way than using `_self` to use the current template as a form theme.